# Encode Set data structure in Golang

Tags: json, go, encoding, interface, set

I have a Set data structure implemented in Go with the basic operations like Add, Remove, Difference, Union. I am trying to send a http request using the json encoder to encode the request body which contains the object of the form `map[string]Set`. The Set data structure is defined below:

```
type Set map[interface{}]struct{}

func NewSet() Set {
    set := make(Set)
    return set
}
```

The encoder looks like this:

```
func (req *Request) BodyContentInJson (val interface{}) error {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)

    if err := enc.Encode(val); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    req.Obj = val
    req.Body = buf
    req.BodySize = int64(buf.Len())
    return nil
}
```

This code fails at

```
if err := enc.Encode(val); err != nil {
            return err
        }
```

giving an error:`{"errors":["json: unsupported type: Set"]}`. Also, the type of `val` is `map[string]interface{}`when I debugged it.

How could I possibly encode and marshal/unmarshal JSON content here using the Go's encoder ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to json serialize a `set`, but `set`s are not json serializable.

Comment: Well set is just a map [interface{}]struct{}, I wonder if I can write my own marhsalling/unmarhalling logic to override the standard json serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own `UnmarshalJSON` method on the `*Set` type which would then be used by the `json.Encoder` to encode the json data into the `Set`. Here's a simple example https://play.golang.org/p/kx1E-jDu5e.

By the way, the reason you're getting the error is because a map key of type `interface{}` is not supported by the `encoding/json` package. (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L697-L699)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks @mkopriva. I'll change the key to `string` from `interface{}`. Also, thanks for the example.

Comment: If you don't need the key to be `interface{}`, and the json you're receiving is of a format like this `{"foo":{}, "123":{}}`, that is, the values are objects (or `null`s), then you don't even have to write your own `UnmarhsalJSON`/`MarshalJSON` methods. https://play.golang.org/p/hgJI6curQu

Comment: Makes sense. I converted the key to be of type `string` and it works like a charm. Thanks again @mkopriva.